# Do I assign something to me or do I assign it to myself? (Me/Myself) in prepositional phrase?

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-objects

In chatting with a coworker, I asked "Should I assign [the task] to *myself*" but then I got discombobulated and wondered if it should have been "to *me*" instead.

I searched for an answer but didn't find anything that seemed to match this situation.  So, which is correct and why?  Does it have to do with it being a prepositional phrase?  Or is it specifically because I am assigning the task *to* me/myself?  Or maybe I'm just overthinking this?

Comment: You could dodge it with "I will take on this job myself" and we don't usually talk about "tasks" in everyday conversation.

Comment: @WeatherVane - True...  but in this particular instance "assign to" is a specific thing one does in the task management system we use (Jira), so to phrase it differently would be awkward and confusing.  Kinda like saying "I will flail my arms and legs about to cross the pool" instead of "I will swim across the pool".  8^)

Comment: '... assign ... to myself' is rarefied', but 'assign ... to me' is unidiomatic. Follow WV's advice. If your system only allows unnatural or incorrect English, we can't really help.

Comment: @Roger you said you are "chatting to a co-worker", not to a bot. Your example describing swimming is pretty much the *opposite* of my suggestion, and more like your original attempt.

Comment: People — what? *I assigned the task to myself* is a perfectly correct and natural usage of a reflexive pronoun with a ditransitive verb. As is [*I mailed the package to myself.*](https://parentingpatch.com/reflexive-pronouns-english-grammar/)

Comment: @WeatherVane - We might not talk about tasks in everyday conversation, but in the world of "scrum" , we definitely do and the convention is that "jiras" (tasks) are *assigned* to people.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - Bingo!  You're absolutely right and your example makes it obvious.  if you want to make that an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Should I assign the task to myself?***

Yes, you should. No one else can assign the task to yourself. Nor can you assign the task to anyone else’s self.

*I assigned the task to myself* displays a perfectly correct and natural usage of a reflexive pronoun with a ditransitive verb — as does *I mailed the package to myself*.

Here are some more examples of reflexive pronouns with ditransitive verbs:

> **Reflexive Pronouns as Indirect Objects**
>
> *I bought myself a new sweater.*
>
> *You should get yourself something to eat.*
>
> **Reflexive Pronouns as Prepositional Complements**
>
> *Did you give the award to yourself?*
>
> *She bought a new car for herself.*
>
> <sub>Source: [Reflexive Pronouns in English
> Grammar](https://parentingpatch.com/reflexive-pronouns-english-grammar/)</sub>

Comment: On rare occasion you can even find reflexive pronouns used as direct objects of ditransitive verbs. For example, George Bernard Shaw in *The Doctor’s Dilemma* wrote: **“I gave him myself** and all that I had that he might grow to his full height with plenty of sunshine. If I lost faith in him, it would mean the wreck and failure of my life. I should go back to Cornwall and die.”

Comment: Although _assign_ can be used as a ditransitive verb as in _He assigned me a difficult task_, I don't think _assign_ in the OP's example is being used as a ditransitive verb, because neither _myself_ nor _to myself_ is an indirect object of the verb. Moreover, the issue of whether to use a reflexive noun has little to do with whether a ditransitive verb is used. I think the issue of whether to use a reflexive noun is equally applicable to cases like _I was talking to myself_ /?? _me_, where _talking_ is being used not as a ditransitive verb or a monotransitive verb but as an intransitive verb.

Comment: @tchrist: Good one. *Myself* can — mm, maybe sometimes — have a non-reflexive sense. From OED: *In noun-like use: my being or personality; my own or very self. In some uses treated like a noun phrase my self.*

Comment: @JK2: In both *He assigned me a difficult task* and *I assigned myself a difficult task*, we have indirect objects — *me* and *myself*, respectively.

Comment: I didn't say anything that would suggest that _me_ and _myself_ are not an indirect object in _He assigned me a difficult task_ and _I assigned myself a difficult task_, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion that it should have been "to me" is actually not wrong. If I understand it correctly, the context in which you uttered the question to your colleague justifies this kind of reading:

> Should I assign [the task] to *myself*, instead of assigning it to *someone else*?

If this reading is correct in context, then you can use *me* instead of *myself*:

> Should I assign [the task] to *me*, instead of assigning it to *someone else*?

Here, non-reflexive *me* is possible because it emphasizes the contrast between *me* and *someone else*. And reflexive *myself* is also possible in the same context.

Comment: Yep, this situation is ripe for an override.